# Popping a vector from a queue

Tags: c++, vector, stl, queue, stdvector

I have a queue of vector and want to the front of the queue to another vector , but it is showing an error . How could i accomplish this task ?

```
queue< vector<int> > que;
vector<int> vec;
vec = que.front() ;
vec = que.pop();
```

Showing error in the third line .

Answer (score 1):

[*`std::queue::pop`*](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/queue/pop) doesn't return any value

<sup>Assuming `que.front` is a typo, you missed function call `()`</sup>

Answer (score 0):

You have an error in your syntax, it should be `vec = que.front();`

More reference can be found in this [link](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/front/).